# I installed OpenGL python library with pip, but it doesn't work when I tried to import it using PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm, pyopengl

I am using manjaro linux.

I tried to install OpenGL python library. I ran

```
pip install PyOpenGL PyOpenGL_accelerate
```

It seemed to work fine, and said it had installed. When I ran import OpenGL in PyCharm it simply returned

```
/home/jackgreen/PycharmProjects/openGLtest/venv/bin/python /home/jackgreen/PycharmProjects/openGLtest/main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jackgreen/PycharmProjects/openGLtest/main.py", line 1, in <module>
    from OpenGL import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'OpenGL'
```

in the console.

Comment: Are you activating your virtual environment before installing via PIP ?

Comment: @tomgalpin What do you mean by activating my virtual environment?

Comment: @tomgalpin If you mean a virtual machine? No. I have linux installed on my computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the look of your path `/home/jackgreen/PycharmProjects/openGLtest/venv/bin/python`
It looks as if you are running from a virtual environment. However you don't specify if you have activated this environment before doing the PIP install.

See [the python docs here](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/guides/installing-using-pip-and-virtual-environments/#activating-a-virtual-environment)

You need to activate the environment then do the PIP install.

> As long as your virtual environment is activated pip will install packages into that specific environment and you’ll be able to import and use packages in your Python application

Try

```
source /home/jackgreen/PycharmProjects/openGLtest/venv/bin/activate
```

Then do the PIP Install

Comment: If you mean a virtual machine? No. I have linux installed on my computer.

Comment: No i mean virtual environment within python . the fact that you have "venv" in your python path would suggest that you are indeed in a virtual env even if you dont mean to be

Comment: Ah yeah, that was it. Pycharm works in a virtual environment. Thx, I got it working!